# Which is the simplest way to define a dropdown box in Django?

Tags: django, dropdownbox

I have a simple `table`, with 2 fields, `code` and `description`, and I need to generate a dropdown box on the table's values in `Django`.

I want to display the `description`, but the selection to be done on the `code` value instead.
Is it possible to do this in a simple way? The `to_field_name` doesn't seem to help me too much.

```
class ChoiceTest (forms.Form):  
    field_cd1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=ViewChoiceTest.objects.values_list(“**code**", flat=True), to_field_name=**description**, label="Choice ", required=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this your model

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  GENDER = (
       ('male', 'Male'),
       ('female', 'Female'),)
  gender = models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=GENDER)
```

and if you want a dynamic dropdown where you want to add and delete the choices than you can relate it with ForeignKey